# Not able to generate Circe Decoder when using with Cats and Refined Types

Tags: scala-cats, circe, refined

I wrote this code

```scala
import io.circe._
import io.circe.refined._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._
import eu.timepit.refined.auto._

final case class Translation(lang: LanguageCode, name: ProductName)
final case class Product(id: ProductId, names: List[Translation])

object Translation {
    implicit val decode: Decoder[Translation] = Decoder.forProduct2("lang", "name")(Translation.apply)
    implicit val encode: Encoder[Translation] = Encoder.forProduct2("lang", "name")(t => (t.lang, t.name))
}

object Product {
    implicit val decode: Decoder[Product] = Decoder.forProduct2("id", "names")(Product.apply)
    implicit val encode: Encoder[Product] = Encoder.forProduct2("id", "names")(p => (p.id, p.names))
}
```

This works fine and it compiles. but if I change my Product Type to use a cats non-empty set.

```scala
final case class Product(id: ProductId, names: NonEmptySet[Translation])
```

I get a compile time error

```
could not find implicit value for parameter decodeA1:
io.circe.Decoder[cats.data.NonEmptySet[com.abhi.models.Translation]]"
```

What can I do so that it auto-generates the decoder for the NonEmptySet just like it does for the List?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [circe source code](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/1b64fc2ab95d80f9d61701e393e6dc15b147266f/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Decoder.scala#L1056) it provides a `Decoder[NonEmptySet[A]]` if given a `Decoder[A]` and a `Order[A]`.

```scala
implicit final def decodeNonEmptySet[A](implicit decodeA: Decoder[A], orderA: Order[A]): Decoder[NonEmptySet[A]] =
    new NonEmptySeqDecoder[A, SortedSet, NonEmptySet[A]](decodeA) {
      final protected def createBuilder(): Builder[A, SortedSet[A]] = SortedSet.newBuilder[A](Order.catsKernelOrderingForOrder(orderA))
      final protected val create: (A, SortedSet[A]) => NonEmptySet[A] = (h, t) => NonEmptySet(h, t)
    }
```

My guess is you're missing an implicit for `Order[Translation]`.